# How to configure Kile livepreview with -shell-escape

Tags: shell-escape, kile

I'm looking to configure kile-livepreview on Ubuntu with `-shell-escape` so that when I've saved the minted environment is compiled.

I'm successfully configured the PDFLatex and it works flawlessly. I couldn't find any information about how to configure it under Kile's configure menu or `kilerc`.

Is it possible to modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Open `kilerc` and navigate to the section `[Tool/LivePreview-PDFLaTeX/Default]`. Add `-shell-escape` to the `options` field under this section.

Comment: Are there any GUI to achieve this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can easily use a text editor. You usually use Ctrl+F in most text editors to search for 

`[Tool/LivePreview-PDFLaTeX/Default]` 

Once you're there you'll find a line that starts with `options` (mine looked like this: `options=-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%dir_target %source`). 

Prepend `-shell-escape` to the options so that you get something like this: 

`options=-synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%dir_target %source`

Comment: No problem with finding and editing the file. Maybe you can enrich your answer with the above comment.

Comment: For the ones on Windows with Kile installed from Microsoft Store I had trouble finding kilerc file: `dir /s %userprofile%\kilerc` Open with notepad, find `Tool/LivePreview-PDFLaTeX` and in options add -shell-escape: `options=-shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%dir_target %source`